# Is the function $F(x)=\int _{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be such that $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx<\infty $.

Define $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by $F(x)=\int _{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$

Does it follow that :

1. $f$ is continuous?
2. $F$ is uniformly continuous?
3. $|f|<M$ for some $M>0$?

I think $1$ is false since we can take 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x\in [0,1]$ } \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$2$ is true since $|F(x_1)-F(x_2)|=|\int _{x_1}^{x_2} f(t)dt| \leq \int _{x_1}^{x_2}| f(t)|dt$

**Since $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx<\infty  \implies |f(x)|\leq M.$

Is the statement marked with ** true as that is required to prove $2,3$?

Comment: @NormalHuman;$F$ is given to be continuous only not uniformly continuous ;how to prove that

Comment: @NormalHuman; how to prove that $F$ is continuous?

Comment: @NormalHuman; if $|f|$ is not bounded how can I prove that $F$ is continuous ;can you please supply a proof

Comment: [Sure, here's some reading for you](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm).

Comment: Given that |f| is integrable,it does not follow that f is, over any interval. You should include integrability of f in the hypotheses.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x,x\in\mathbb{N}\\ 
0,x\not\in\mathbb{N}
\end{matrix}\right.$

So $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}f(x).dx=0$, but $f$ does not have supremum in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore the statement 3 is false.

Comment: thank you very much ;but can you please help to prove 2 false

Answer (score 2):

Lets get everything together. I assume that all integrals are Riemann integrals. Recall basic facts:

A. When $f$ has countable number of discontinuities on $[a,b]$ then it is R-integrable on this interval.

B. The condition $\int_{- \infty}^\infty |f(x)| \mathrm{d} x < \infty$ means that both lmits $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^b |f(x)| \mathrm{d} x $ and $\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} \int_b^0 |f(x)| \mathrm{d} x $ exist in finite sense

C. The function $ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \mathrm{d} t$ makes sense, is continuous and differentiable at points of continuity of $f$

Hence:

Ad 1,3. No, need not be, you already have example that contradicts it.

Ad 2. Yes, it is as a continuous function with finite limits at infinities. To prove it you take interval $[-M,M]$ outside of which you have control over functions behavior due to finite limits. Inside this interval the function is uniformly continuous. Take this two together and you have overall uniform continuity.

Comment: how do you know that $F$ is continuous?it will be great if you could share a proof here or some facts relating that